# TYPO3 Extbase - Does Dependency Injection work in Service Classes?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using a Service of type auth for adding an API based login.
I tried to add a User with the FrontendUserRepository of Extbase via `@inject`.
But this doesn't work.

Am i doing something wrong or is this to early to use the Dependency Injection?

P.S.: I know i can use the repository the following way:

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
$this->frontendUserRepository = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Domain\\Repository\\FrontendUserRepository');
```

Comment: Note: In TYPO3 ≧ 7.6 the first line changed to `$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DI with the `@Inject` annotation works only for objects loaded by a TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager instance. The auth services are beeing instantiated using `GeneralUtility::makeInstanceService()` which in turn uses `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` (see `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\AbstractUserAuthentication::checkAuthentication()`), so the `@Inject` annotation has no effect.
You must use the workaround mentioned already by yourself.

Comment: You are right. But please have look at this article about the [ways to inject](https://gist.github.com/NamelessCoder/3b2e5931a6c1af19f9c3f8b46e74f837).
The `@inject` -way might not be the best even if its shorter.
I spend many hours of troubleshooting just for the requirements of `@inject` for TYPO3

Answer (score 0):

[typo3 7.6] 
I think in the auth service all the extbase stuff in not proper loaded. I have lots of errors while trying to use extbase repos in a auth service (which are running great in context of controller). I found one link about a possible init of the missing parts: [Extbase innerhalb eines TYPO3 Authentication Services verwenden](http://nerdcenter.de/extbase-typo3-authentication-service/)